# sympy.subs - wrong substitution

Tags: python, sympy

I have this equation:

```
(1 - tau2)**3 + (tau2-tau1)**5
```

And I want to substitute (1-tau2) by (1-tau3). However, I get the wrong result.

This is my code:

```
tau1,tau2,tau3= symbols('tau1,tau2,tau3')

exp= (1-tau2)**3+(tau2-tau1)**5
res=exp.subs((1-tau2),(1-tau3))

print('exp:',exp)
print('res:',res)
```

And the result is:

```
exp= (1 - tau2)**3 + (-tau1 + tau2)**5
res= (1 - tau3)**3 + (-tau1 + tau3)**5
```

But it should be:

```
res= (1 - tau3)**3 + (-tau1 + tau2)**5
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you want a smart substitution -- in this case, recognizing that your substitution is equivalent to replacing `tau2` with `tau3` -- and sometimes you want an exact substitution. In case of the latter, use `xreplace`:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> (1-x)**3+(x-y)**5
(1 - x)**3 + (x - y)**5
>>> _.xreplace({1-x: z})
z**3 + (x - y)**5
```